# How to add a image slideshow in fragment using android studio

Tags: android-fragments

I create a android app using android studio.In home fragment I need  to add a image slideshow and it should be animated like in most of the homepage in websites.if user want to see the further details of the image then move to the another activity which have the details by touching the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [link](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/) that shows how to do this. I am assuming you want a carousal type of slideshow.

Note: I know SO requires code to be pasted instead of links but the code is too big and the question is very general.